# Two Windows 10 computers not communicating

Tags: windows-10, networking, workgroup

I recently bought a refurbed Dell Optiplex 3020 and a refurbed Dell Latitude E6540, both of which came with Windows 10 Pro, Version 21H1. While I am coming to terms with Windows 10, so far I am having limited and somewhat confusing success in getting the two to communicate. I quickly learned to ignore any Internet help that spoke of Homegroup and any that did not specifically address the Pro version.

For reference, this is the configuration I'm dealing with:

Media64LT (in WORKGROUP),
Dell Inc. Latitude E6540 00,
Windows 10 Professional (x64) Version 21H1 (build 19043.1466),
Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN (5.0Ghz wifi)

Media64 (in WORKGROUP),
Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3020 00,
Windows 10 Professional (x64) Version 21H1 (build 19043.1466),
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller (Ethernet)

TP-LINK N750 Model TL-WDR4300,
Firmware: 3.14.3 Build 151104 Rel.45874n

ZoneAlarm Free Firewall version: 15.8.181.18901,
Vsmon version: 15.8.116.18864,
Driver version: 15.1.29.17237

When I invoke the Network view from Media64LT, I can "see" Media64LT and the router. I can open Media64LT and access the shared folders. No sign of Media64.

From Media64, I see Media64, Media64LT and the router. I can open Media64 and access folders. But attempts to open Media64LT returns the error message "Windows cannot access \MEDIA64LT." It appears to be a Permission issue.

I followed a series of steps from https://thegeekpage.com turning on SMB1.0 feature, changing Startup type FDRP, turning on network discovery, file and printer sharing, turning off password protected sharing, etc. All to no avail.

I have found nothing in the router configuration nor the firewall settings that jump out as being a problem, but I confess I'm stumped.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Advanced Network and Sharing Center::  Turn ON Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing, Password Protected Sharing on both. Make sure (Computer Properties) that both are on the same WORKGROUP.  Restart both and test.

Comment: John - per the https://thegeekpage.com/ procedure, network discovery, file and print sharing were turned on. Password protected sharing is turned off in anticipation of later connecting a local iMac needing access to the printer. The WORKGROUP is the same on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your active networks in the "Network and Sharing Center" in the "Control Panel" both show "Private network".
If one of the networks show public this could explain why they have trouble connecting.
Public is less trusting of other computers.

Comment: Private and Guest/Public both have to be turned on or the wifi connected machine complains about Network Discovery not being on.